# Get indented html using tidyhtml in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmltidy

I'm trying to beautify html from string using tidyhtml5managed, code is:

```
using (Document doc = Document.FromString(myhtmltext)) //<html><head><...
            {
                doc.IndentAttributes = true;
                doc.CleanAndRepair();

                Literal1.Text = doc.ToString();
            }
```

I got  output like this

```
TidyManaged.Document
```

My question is how to get html beautified output? Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

What about reading the manual? Just call `Save()` instead of `ToString()`

```
using (Document doc = Document.FromString(dirtyHtml))
            {
                doc.OutputBodyOnly = AutoBool.Yes;
                doc.Quiet = true;
                doc.CleanAndRepair();
                string cleanHtml = doc.Save();

                Console.WriteLine("Clean HTML: " + cleanHtml);
            }
```